# c# Recursion stackoverflowcrash

Tags: c#, recursion

I am building a minesweeper game in C#, and one of my functions keeps crashing the program. The erorr message is `Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.` I tried to find where is the problem in my recursion, but I didn't find it. The problem only happen if `Openk` is called, so I am pretty sure the problem is there. I tried to find if there is an infinite recursion, but didn't find it. What could be the problem?

```
  public void Openk(int row, int col)
    {
        if (sqrs[row, col].IsBlank() == true)
        {
            for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
                {                         
                    if (IsValid(row - i, col - j))
                    {                           
                            if (sqrs[row - i, col - j].IsMine() == false)
                                sqrs[row - i, col - j].Open();
                            Openk(row - i, col - j);

                    }                      
                }
            }
        }

    }
    public bool IsValid(int row, int col)
    {
        if (row >= n || row <= 0 || col >= n || col <= 0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: If you break the problem down and unit test smaller parts, you'll know what works and what doesn't.

Comment: `if (i == 0 && j == 0)` seems to be floating.  Did you want to do something there?

Comment: `sqrs[row , col] = sqrs[row , col ];` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to check if this is a valid conrdination.And I did debug and didnt find the problame otherwide i had no reason to ask.

Comment: `if (IsValid(row - i, col - j))` only occurs `if (i == 0 && j == 0)`. Typo here (and *not* in your code), or is this the real code? If so, debugging should help you find this (also, using your IDE's indentation tools will help you spot this too).

Comment: This kind of exception tends to be caused by too many recursive calls or infinite recursion.

Comment: I don't see how this logic can't be an infinite recursion. Every valid set will cause a recursive call.

Comment: I also don't get why the loop starts at negative one. That's going to do things that I don't think you expect.

Comment: The "if (i == 0 && j == 0)" was a typo I forgot to remove it(it didnt cause the problame).The loop tries to open the known squares. squares with no value(IsBlank) and open them. The loop starts from one beacouse i want to checkallthe squares{row-1,col}{row-1,col-1}{row-1,col} { row-1,col} and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you keep looping and executing `Openk` on the same middle square each time. Maybe it is because of the unguarded `if` statement. It goes like this in your code.

1. You pass the selected coordinates of a square, say [5,5].
2. Then you loop a row before 5 (4), row 5, and a row after 5 (6).
3. For each row, your loop a square before the selected column 5 (4), column 5, and and the next column of 5 (6).
4. In your code, only when you reach the middle square (i = 0, j = 0), you execute the checking of square if it is a mine, and if it is not mine, you pass the selected coordinates after subtracting with zeros (i = 0, j = 0), which effectively loops the same spot again!

.

```
public void Openk(int row, int col)
{
    if (sqrs[row, col].IsBlank() == true)
    {
        for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++)
            {
                // Only execute the following code when checking the middle square, where i = 0, and j = 0.
                if (i == 0 && j == 0) // Notice the braces I added, the code has the same effect if you don't type them.
                {   
                    // This if statement has not effect.
                    if (IsValid(row - i, col - j)) // It is like if (true)
                    {
                        if (sqrs[row-i, col-j].IsMine() == false)
                            sqrs[row - i, col - j].Open();
                        Openk(row - i, col - j); // row - 0 = row, col - 0 = col, your looping infinitely here.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```